# javax.comm.PortInUseException in SMSLib

Tags: smslib

i am trying to use SMSLib to send sms to mobiles from my pc. I am using my Nokia 5130 GSM phone to send messages, but its not working. Heres the code i am using.

```
package sms;
import org.smslib.AGateway;
import org.smslib.IOutboundMessageNotification;
import org.smslib.Library;
import org.smslib.Message.MessageEncodings;
import org.smslib.OutboundMessage;
import org.smslib.Service;
import org.smslib.modem.SerialModemGateway;

public class SendMessage
{
public void doIt() throws Exception {
 OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();
 System.out.println("Example: Send message from a serial gsm modem.");
 System.out.println(Library.getLibraryDescription());
 System.out.println("Version: " + Library.getLibraryVersion());
 SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com12", "COM12", 115200, "Nokia", "Nokia 5130 XPressMusic USB Modem");


gateway.setInbound(true);
gateway.setOutbound(true);
gateway.setSimPin("0000");

gateway.setSmscNumber("+919886005444");
Service.getInstance().setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification);
Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
Service.getInstance().startService();
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Modem Information:");
System.out.println("  Manufacturer: " + gateway.getManufacturer());
System.out.println("  Model: " + gateway.getModel());
System.out.println("  Serial No: " + gateway.getSerialNo());
System.out.println("  SIM IMSI: " + gateway.getImsi());
System.out.println("  Signal Level: " + gateway.getSignalLevel() + " dBm");
System.out.println("  Battery Level: " + gateway.getBatteryLevel() + "%");
System.out.println();
// Send a message synchronously.
OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage("+917829903913", "Sample msg");
msg.setEncoding(MessageEncodings.ENC7BIT);
msg.setSrcPort(0);
msg.setDstPort(66500);
Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);

System.out.println(msg);

System.out.println("Now Sleeping - Hit <enter> to terminate.");
System.in.read();
Service.getInstance().stopService();
}

public class OutboundNotification implements IOutboundMessageNotification {

public void process(AGateway gateway, OutboundMessage msg) {
System.out.println("Outbound handler called from Gateway: " + gateway.getGatewayId());
System.out.println(msg);
 }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
SendMessage app = new SendMessage();
try {
app.doIt();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

And here is the error message i am getting. Please help as i don't have much knowledge on these.

```
run:
Example: Send message from a serial gsm modem.
SMSLib: A Java API library for sending and receiving SMS via a GSM modem or other supported   gateways.
This software is distributed under the terms of the Apache v2.0 License.
Web Site: http://smslib.org
Version: 3.5.1
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (smslib).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
org.smslib.GatewayException: Comm library exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.comm.PortInUseException: Port currently owned by Unknown Windows Application
    at org.smslib.modem.SerialModemDriver.connectPort(SerialModemDriver.java:102)
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.connect(AModemDriver.java:114)
    at org.smslib.modem.ModemGateway.startGateway(ModemGateway.java:189)
    at org.smslib.Service$1Starter.run(Service.java:276)
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure no other application is listening on `COM12` . `javax.comm.PortInUseException:` occurred because your code tries to register `COM12` which is not available.

After you have copied all the necessary jars amd dll files to the right location, this should work. You also need a 32 bit JDK so you might have to download JDK for a 32bit if you don't have one else you will get `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:`

I ran this code and it works. Also rememeber to set setSmscNumber to your SIM provider's looks like you still have the default one (example one)

Cheers
PB

Answer (score 1):

There is an application related to your phone(like Nokia Suite) that works on the PC and make a **connection** with your phone when connecting your phone to the PC, make sure you **turn off** all such applications and make your connection just a physical one.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after I installed the 32 bit java version. Also make sure you use the correct port. com11 in my case.

[image]